# popup html page is not opening in crossrider

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, javascript-framework, crossrider

I am creating a IE Extension using crossrider. In this extension i want to open a html page as popup by clicking the icon in the browser action. when i click the icon the html page is not getting popped up.

background.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) 
{
  appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icon128.png');
  appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('Tax2290 Extension');
  appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({resourcePath:'index.html'});
});
```

extension.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
// Includes remote JS file into extension.js scope
 // Injects remote JS file into HTML page
 appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS('images/feed.js');
// Injects remote CSS file into HTML page
 appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS('images/style.css');

});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my response to the duplicate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052271/how-to-set-html-page-as-popup-in-browser-action-in-crossrider/18055015#18055015)

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]